# Pandas data manipulation

Tags: python, pandas, data-manipulation

I have a matrix, where the rows are some item numbers, the columns are scores for some features called score1, score2, etc.  I want to create 3 new columns called out1, out2, and out3; where out1, out2 or out3 gets the value 1(score1), 2(score2) or 3(score3).  the rules is as follows and please look at the example picture of a matrix
[image of an example as I am not yet allowed to post pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/pq9C9.png)

1. the column with the highest score for an items gets to be placed in out1
2. If there are ties and no highest then all the outs are left blank
3. if the difference between the highest score and the 2nd highest score is less than or equal to 2, then that score is placed in out2
4. if there is tie between the score for out2, then out2 and out3 will be blank
5. if the difference between the 2nd highest score and 3rd highest score is less than equal to 2, then that score is placed in out3
6. if there is tie between the score for out3, then out3 will be blank

Here is a toy matrix

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'items':['item1', 'item2', 'item3', 'item4', 'item-n'],
                  'score0':[11,2,3,10,10],
                  'score1':[6,4,6,6,9],
                  'score2':[9,8,6,8,8],
                  'score-n':[3,0,2,6,2]})
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

Stack Overflow is not for solving your homework problems, but to ask specifics. Anyways a starting point could be to drop the "items" column and use apply for your own written functions:

```
def my_max(arr1d):
    return np.argmax(arr1d)

dfs = df.drop(["items"], axis=1)
col1 = dfs.apply(my_max, axis=1)
```

Here just replace argmax with your own functions.